# how is the reverse() function works?

Tags: c++

I am trying to reverse the k chars for every k, 2k, 3k..etc position, and I used the reverse() function. Why is the reverse(s.begin() + l, s.begin() + r -1) does not change the string at all. If I removed the -1, it will work perfectly.  I am a beginner, please give me some explanation. I appreciate it.

---

```
Input: s = "abcdefg", k = 2
Output: "bacdfeg" 
MyOutput: "abcdefg"
```

---

```
class Solution {
    public:
        string reverseStr(string s, int k) {
            int l = 0;
            int r = min(k, (int)s.length());
    
            while(l < s.length()){
                reverse(s.begin() + l, s.begin() + r -1);
                l += 2*k;
                r = min(l + k, (int)s.length());
            }
            return s;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Tip: Use `const std::string& s` as arguments to avoid accidental mutation and avoid copies.

Comment: Could `r-1` be < 0? If so, that's not valid.

Comment: What are the values of `l` and `r-1` when you call `reverse`?

Comment: Why are you doing the `-1` at all? Why did you think that might be required?

Comment: @ l = 0 and r -1 will be 1. From my thought, it will reverse the s[0] and s[1], but nothing changed.

Comment: off-topic: why is `reverseStr` a method if it does not have state?

Comment: No. `reverse` (like all std algorithms) takes a half open range, i.e. `[l,r)`. The end of the range is not reversed. The `-1` is not needed at all.

Comment: @cigien Thank you for noticing that! Now I know where I messed up.

Comment: No problem. Note that if you had tried this with `k = 3` you would see that elements *are* getting reversed, just not the last element in each subrange.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your logic.  Consider your example, k=2, s="abcdefg"

Your loop does this:

```
while(l < s.length()){
    reverse(s.begin() + l, s.begin() + r -1);
    l += 2*k;
    r = min(l + k, (int)s.length());
}
```

Your first time through, l is 0, and r is 2, calls:

```
reverse(s.begin() + 0, s.begin + 1)
```

the end iterator is immediately after the first element in the range, so you're reversing a single element, which does nothing.

Second time through, l is 4, r is 6

```
reverse(s.begin() + 4, s.begin() + 5)
```

Another 1-element range, reversing does nothing.

And then the loop ends.

I guess the question is, if it works without subtracting 1 from r, then why do you subtract 1 from r?